# Why am I getting NaN error in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, beagleboneblack

In the following code, I get `NaN` for `fulldata`. Everything else has a value of `0`. I don't know why this is happening. What is the problem? What do I need to change?

```
var fulldata = 0;
var pulses = 0;
var flowrate; // liters per minute
var value = 0;
var d = new Date();
var liters = 0;
var gallons = 0;
var cost = 0;
var file = ('/var/lib/cloud9/data.txt');
var oldTime;
var oldAmount = b.readTextFile(file);
var totalCost = oldAmount * 0.00313;

app.listen(8090);
console.log('Server running on: http://' + getIPAddress() + ':8090');

var Sensor = "P8_19";
b.pinMode('P8_19', b.INPUT);
console.log(b.digitalRead('P8_19'));
b.digitalWrite('P8_19', b.HIGH);
oldTime = Date.now();
b.attachInterrupt('P8_19', pulseCounter, b.FALLING);

io.on('connection', function(socket) {

  var tm = setInterval(function() {
    var newTime = Date.now();
    var timeDifference = (newTime - oldTime);

    if (timeDifference > 1000) {
      b.detachInterrupt('P8_19');
      b.pinMode('P8_19', b.INPUT);
      value = b.digitalRead('P8_19');
      //console.log(timeDifference);

      flowrate = (1000.0 / (timeDifference)) * ((pulses) / 4.5);
      //console.log(flowrate);
      oldTime = newTime;

      liters = flowrate / 60;
      console.log(liters + "L");
      gallons = (liters * 0.264);
      var newData = gallons;
      console.log(gallons + "G");
      cost = gallons * 0.00313;
      fulldata += newData;
      totalCost += cost;
      console.log(fulldata);
      console.log("$" + cost);

      socket.emit('water', {'water': fulldata});
      socket.emit('money', {'money': cost});
      socket.emit('month', {'month': totalCost});

      pulses = 0;
      b.attachInterrupt('P8_19', pulseCounter, b.FALLING);
    }
  }, 500);

  socket.on('disconnect', function() {
    oldAmount = (oldAmount + fulldata);
    b.writeTextFile(file, oldAmount);
    clearInterval(tm);
  });

});
```

Comment: use this `totalCost = parseFloat(oldAmount,10) * 0.00313;`

Comment: Unlikely to be the cause. The [*multiplication operator*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.5) coerces operands to Number anyway. `oldAmount = (oldAmount + fulldata)` is more problematic, but that should be a different error.

Comment: Which line gives the NAN error? Are you able to debug it? Maybe set a breakpoint and inspect the var...

Comment: BTW, `flowrate = (1000.0 / (timeDifference)) * ((pulses) / 4.5)` doesn't need all those brackets, it can be just `flowrate = 1000 / timeDifference * pulses / 4.5`.

Comment: Please post the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I made a test harness (http://jsbin.com/korewi/1/) to try to isolate this error, but even with introducing reasonable points of failure, I can only make totalCost be NaN, not fulldata. Ideas?

Comment: For some reason, restarting Cloud9 several times fixed the problem.  I have no idea why.